# How do I select elements of an array given condition?

Tags: python, numpy

Suppose I have a numpy array `x = [5, 2, 3, 1, 4, 5]`, `y = ['f', 'o', 'o', 'b', 'a', 'r']`. I want to select the elements in `y` corresponding to elements in `x` that are greater than 1 and less than 5.

I tried

```
x = array([5, 2, 3, 1, 4, 5])
y = array(['f','o','o','b','a','r'])
output = y[x > 1 & x < 5] # desired output is ['o','o','a']
```

but this doesn't work. How would I do this?

Answer (score 270, accepted):

Your expression works if you add parentheses:

```
>>> y[(1 < x) & (x < 5)]
array(['o', 'o', 'a'], 
      dtype='|S1')
```

Comment: That is nice.. vecMask=1<x generates a vector mask like vecMask=(False, True, ...), which can be just combined with other vector masks. Each element is the condition for taking the elements of a source vector (True) or not (False). This can be used also with the full version numpy.extract(vecMask, vecSrc), or numpy.where(vecMask, vecSrc, vecSrc2).

Comment: @JennyYueJin: It happens because of precedence. (Bitwise) `&` has higher precedence than `<` and `>`, which in turn have higher precedence than (logical) `and`. `x > 1 and x < 5` evaulates the inequalities first and then the logical conjunction; `x > 1 & x < 5` evaluates the bitwise conjunction of `1` and (the values in) `x`, then the inequalities. `(x > 1) & (x < 5)` forces the inequalities to evaluate first, so all of the operations occur in the intended order and the results are all well-defined. [See docs here.](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence)

Comment: @ru111 It works on Python 3.6 too (there is no reason for it to stop working).

Comment: I get "ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()"

Comment: @ru111 you should write `(0 < x) & (x < 10)` (as shown in the answer) instead of `0 < x < 10` which doesn't work for numpy arrays on any Python version.

Comment: If someone is confused on why using the Bitwise 
& operator instead of a logical AND, here is a very good explanations: https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/02.06-boolean-arrays-and-masks.html

Answer (score 44):

IMO OP does not actually want [`np.bitwise_and()` (aka `&`)](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.bitwise_and.html) but actually wants [`np.logical_and()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.logical_and.html) because they are comparing logical values such as `True` and `False` - see this SO post on [logical vs. bitwise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8418295/logical-vs-bitwise) to see the difference.

```
>>> x = array([5, 2, 3, 1, 4, 5])
>>> y = array(['f','o','o','b','a','r'])
>>> output = y[np.logical_and(x > 1, x < 5)] # desired output is ['o','o','a']
>>> output
array(['o', 'o', 'a'],
      dtype='|S1')
```

And equivalent way to do this is with [`np.all()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.all.html) by setting the `axis` argument appropriately.

```
>>> output = y[np.all([x > 1, x < 5], axis=0)] # desired output is ['o','o','a']
>>> output
array(['o', 'o', 'a'],
      dtype='|S1')
```

by the numbers:

```
>>> %timeit (a < b) & (b < c)
The slowest run took 32.97 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
100000 loops, best of 3: 1.15 µs per loop

>>> %timeit np.logical_and(a < b, b < c)
The slowest run took 32.59 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.17 µs per loop

>>> %timeit np.all([a < b, b < c], 0)
The slowest run took 67.47 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
100000 loops, best of 3: 5.06 µs per loop
```

so using `np.all()` is slower, but `&` and `logical_and` are about the same.

Comment: You need to be a little careful about how you speak about what's evaluated.  For example, in `output = y[np.logical_and(x > 1, x < 5)]`, `x < 5` *is* evaluated (possibly creating an enormous array), even though it's the second argument, because that evaluation happens outside of the function.  IOW, `logical_and` gets passed two already-evaluated arguments.  This is different from the usual case of `a and b`, in which `b` isn't evaluated if `a` is truelike.

Comment: there is no difference between bitwise_and() and logical_and() for boolean arrays

Comment: I've been searching ages for the 'or' alternative and this reply gave me some much needed relief! Thank you so much. (np.logical_or), OBVIOUSLY...

Comment: @J.Massey [a pipe `|` (_aka_ `np.bitwise_or`)](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.bitwise_or.html) might also work, _eg_: `(a < b) | (a > c)`

Answer (score 25):

Add one detail to @J.F. Sebastian's and @Mark Mikofski's answers:
If one wants to get the corresponding indices (rather than the actual values of array), the following code will do:

For satisfying multiple (all) conditions:

```
select_indices = np.where( np.logical_and( x > 1, x < 5) )[0] #   1 < x <5
```

For satisfying multiple (or) conditions:

```
select_indices = np.where( np.logical_or( x < 1, x > 5 ) )[0] # x <1 or x >5
```

Comment: Note that numpy.where will not just return an array of the indices, but will instead return a tuple (the output of condition.nonzero()) containing arrays - in this case, `(the array of indices you want,)`, so you'll need `select_indices = np.where(...)[0]` to get the result you want and expect.

Answer (score 6):

I like to use `np.vectorize` for such tasks. Consider the following:

```
>>> # Arrays
>>> x = np.array([5, 2, 3, 1, 4, 5])
>>> y = np.array(['f','o','o','b','a','r'])

>>> # Function containing the constraints
>>> func = np.vectorize(lambda t: t>1 and t<5)

>>> # Call function on x
>>> y[func(x)]
>>> array(['o', 'o', 'a'], dtype='<U1')
```

The advantage is you can add many more types of constraints in the vectorized function.

Hope it helps.

Comment: This is not a good way to do indexing in NumPy (it will be very slow).

Answer (score 1):

Actually I would do it this way:

L1 is the index list of elements satisfying condition 1;(maybe you can use `somelist.index(condition1)` or `np.where(condition1)` to get L1.)

Similarly, you get L2, a list of elements satisfying condition 2;

Then you find intersection using `intersect(L1,L2)`.

You can also find intersection of multiple lists if you get multiple conditions to satisfy.

Then you can apply index in any other array, for example, x.

Answer (score 0):

For 2D arrays, you can do this. Create a 2D mask using the condition. Typecast the condition mask to int or float, depending on the array, and multiply it with the original array.

```
In [8]: arr
Out[8]: 
array([[ 1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.],
       [ 6.,  7.,  8.,  9., 10.]])

In [9]: arr*(arr % 2 == 0).astype(np.int) 
Out[9]: 
array([[ 0.,  2.,  0.,  4.,  0.],
       [ 6.,  0.,  8.,  0., 10.]])
```