# Logical vs bitwise

Tags: python, logical-operators

What the different between logical operators `and`, `or` and bitwise analogs `&`, `|` in usage? Is there any difference in efficiency in various solutions?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Logical operators operate on logical values, while bitwise operators operate on integer bits. Stop thinking about performance, and use them for they're meant for.

```
if x and y: # logical operation
   ...
z = z & 0xFF # bitwise operation
```

Comment: On the performance issue: normally the difference between these low-level operations impacts on the overall performance of the program in the order of 10**6 or more iterations. If you (OP!) need to perform that operation that many times, chances are you should switch altogether to a numeric/scientific library like numpy/scipy.

Comment: On the performance issue.  Since `and` and `or` are "short-circuit" operators that work left-to-right, you'll find that `a and (something hellishly expensive)` runs **completely** differently from `a & (something hellishly expensive)` when `a` is False.  Short-circuit evaluation isn't a negligible effect at all.  It's profound.

Answer (score 17):

**Bitwise** = Bit by bit checking

```
# Example

Bitwise AND: 1011 & 0101 = 0001
Bitwise OR: 1011 | 0101 = 1111
```

**Logical** = Logical checking or in other words, you can say `True/False` checking

```
# Example

# both are non-zero so the result is True
Logical AND: 1011 && 0101 = 1 (True)

# one number is zero so the result is False 
Logical AND: 1011 && 0000 = 0 (False)  

# one number is non-zero so the result is non-zero which is True
Logical OR: 1011 || 0000 = 1 (True)

# both numbers are zero so the result is zero which is False
Logical OR: 0000 || 0000 = 0 (False)
```

Comment: A good example would be `2 & 1` producing (integer) `0`, because their set bits don't intersect.  But `2 && 1` is (boolean) `true` because `(2 != 0) && (1 != 0)` is `true && true`.  That's important for understanding that `&` isn't a drop-in replacement except for not short-circuiting.

Comment: I don't think `1011 && 0000` is a very good illustration because it's 0 or false with & or &&.  (In like C++, even the type is different: `&&` produces a `bool`, `&` produces an integer of the type of the inputs.  If Python has a bool type, I'd assume it's like that.)

Comment: @PeterCordes thanks for pointing out a better example in your comment. I guess this can be added to the answer too.

Answer (score 11):

Logical operators are used for booleans, since `true` equals 1 and `false` equals 0. If you use (binary) numbers other than 1 and 0, then any number that's not zero becomes a one. 
 Ex: `int x = 5;` (101 in binary) `int y = 0;` (0 in binary) In this case, printing `x && y` would print `0`, because 101 was changed to 1, and 0 was kept at zero: this is the same as printing `true && false`, which returns `false` (0). 
 
On the other hand, bitwise operators perform an operation on every single bit of the two operands (hence the term "bitwise"). 
 Ex: `int x = 5; int y = 8;` printing `x | y` (bitwise OR) would calculate this: 
        *00*`0101` (5)
`| 1000` (8)
 ----------- 
 `=  1101` (13) 
Meaning it would print `13`.