# Strange Logic Behavior with Variable and Number

Tags: python, logic, boolean-logic, inequality

Say I define `a` and `b` as follows:

```
a = 1
b = 1
```

Then I test:

```
a == 1
#True

5>4
#True

a==1 & b==1
#True

5>4 & 4>3
#True

a==1 & 5>4
#False
```

What is going on with the last one? I would like to be able to test the last inequality and get the result of `True`.

Comment: `&` is bitwise AND. You want `&&`.

Comment: @Blorgbeard It is Python, so `and`, not `&&`.

Comment: Oops, thanks @kennytm and Padraic, you're correct.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8418295/logical-vs-bitwise

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Python `&` is for bit operations with numbers, not logic. Use `and` and `or` instead.

Comment: In the last example, the `&` operator takes precedence on the `==` operator. So it is evaluated first, like this: `a == (1 & 5) > 4`. Then `a == 1 > 5` which is converted to `int(True) > 5`, which is `False`.

Answer (score -1):

> Unlike C, all comparison operations in Python have the same priority, which is lower than that of any arithmetic, shifting or bitwise operation. Also unlike C, expressions like a < b < c have the interpretation that is conventional in mathematics:

Which means:

```
a==1 & 5>4 is equal to 
a == ( 1 % 5 ) > 4
a == 1 > 4
True > 4

False
```