# different between "&" and "and" in expressions

Tags: expression, operator-precedence, paradigms

I have this question and I'm really confused !
What different between "&" and "and" in expressions ?
and how can I compute the result of of (and, &) operations, should I convert the numbers to binary ? 
[image]

Comment: What language are you asking about?

Comment: Bitwise vs logical, [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8418295/logical-vs-bitwise).