# difference between bitwise and logical OR

Tags: c++, boolean, bitwise-or, logical-or

What is the difference between bitwise and logical OR operations when it comes to boolean variables in C++? In the integer domain, it is clear but when it comes to boolean is there any performance advantage or behavioral change between both of them?

bool VAR = TRUE , BOOL VAR2= TRUE

Is there a difference in VAR | VAR2  & VAR || VAR2

Comment: Your code example is not valid C++.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8418295/logical-vs-bitwise

Answer (score 5):

For performance differences, logical OR short-circuits (e.g., in `op1 || op2`, if `op1` evaluates to `true`, `op2` is not evaluated), but bit-wise doesn't. This also creates a behavior difference:

```
if (op1 == nullptr || fn(op1)) { /* ... */ }
```

This code will never call `fn` with `nullptr` because of the short-circuit behavior. On the other hand, if the logical OR was replaced with bit-wise, `fn` would always be called. If `fn` has side effects or undesirable behavior when called with `nullptr`, this creates a behavior difference.

Comment: It is worth noting that the above is equivalent to `if (op1 == nullptr) if (fn(op1))`, as in it will have two branches in the generated code. `if ((x == 0) | (y == 0))` on the other hand will always compare `x` and `y` but only do one branch. For simple condition the short circuiting of a logical or can often cost more than evaluating the second condition. As always *benchmark before optimizing*.

Comment: Agree, premature optimization is the root of all evil. Hadn't thought of the extra branch instruction generation though!

Answer (score 2):

Bitwise and logical operators are quite different:

- Logical operators work on the logical values of the variables and give back `true` or `false` which are logical values
- Bitwise operators work on the single bits of the variables

Briefly the bitwise operator consider the single bits of 2 varibales: `&` operation between 2 bitmasks gives back a bitmask where the compared bit is 1 if both the relative bits in the original mask are 1; `|` operation between 2 bitmasks gives back a bitmask where the compared bit is 1 if at least one of the relative bits in the original mask is 1.

The result of a bitwise peration depends on the size of a variable and its representation in bits.
I made a little exercise trying to make bitwise operation on bool variables and you can run it on your machine. I think the result depends on the compiler and the architecture; anyway in my test the size of bool is 1 byte (8 bits) and in the case it's true just the first bit is 1:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    bool b1 = true;
    bool b2 = true;

    std::cout << "size of bool:" << sizeof(bool) << std::endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < 8 * sizeof(bool); i++)
    {
        std::cout << "bitwise operation | on bit:" << i << " result:" << (b1 | (1 << i)) << std::endl;
        std::cout << "bitwise operation & on bit:" << i << " result:" << (b1 & (1 << i)) << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: @PeteBecker you are rigth... corrected