# Numpy value error - the truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Edit: Question updated - I should have asked:

Why is this:

```
new_x = x[(0<x<10) & (20<x<40)]
```

giving me "ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()"?

The original question I posted did not reflect the problem I was having (apologies - my actual conditions are more complicated and I had oversimplified it). Original question below:

> I have a numpy array x and I want to create a new array of x elements
>   satisfying x>0 and x<10. I have tried all the following:
>
> ```
> new_x = x[(x>0) and (x<10)]
>
> new_x = x[(x>0) & (x<10)]
>
> new_x = x[np.logical_and(x>0, x<10)]
>
> new_x = x[np.where(x>0, x<10)]
>
> new_x = x[np.all(x>0, x<10)]
>
> new_x = x[np.all((x>0) and (x<10))]
>
> new_x = x[np.all(x>0) and np.all(x<10)]
>
> new_x = x[np.any(x>0, x<10)]
> ```
>
> and they all give the following error:
>
> > ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
>
> I have ran out of ideas. I realise this may be a duplicate question
>   but I have consulted
>   [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3030480/numpy-array-how-to-select-indices-satisfying-multiple-conditions)
>   and
>   [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16343752/numpy-where-function-multiple-conditions)
>   and many others which did not help as I keep getting the same value
>   error.
>
> Edit: Fixed typo (x<0 and x>10) --> (x>0 and x<10)

Comment: Why not simply using the `filter` function?

Comment: Use the last version, but add additional brackets: `selection = np.any((x<0, x>10))`. The first argument of np.any need to be an iterable, the second would be the axis.

Comment: The second one is correct. You are probably doing something else wrong.

Comment: @rll because that would give you a `filter` object.... clearly, the OP is looking to work with `numpy.ndarray` objects.

Comment: @ayhan yea, the second and third one should definitely work. I suspect that `x` may be a `dtype=object` array that contains *other array objects*. That would potentially produce these errors.

Comment: @ru111 what does `x.dtype, x.shape` give you?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga int64 and (200000,) - but I think my conditions just need to be revised (they are a bit complicated). If it was the problem with my condition statements the error message is very misleading though.

Comment: @ru111 you are going to need to provide a [mcve] or else one can only guess.

Answer (score 2):

I'm confused with the logical statements.  How can a value be both less than 0 and greater than 10?

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: x = np.arange(-10,20)

In [3]: x
Out[3]:
array([-10,  -9,  -8,  -7,  -6,  -5,  -4,  -3,  -2,  -1,   0,   1,   2,
     3,   4,   5,   6,   7,   8,   9,  10,  11,  12,  13,  14,  15,

In [5]: x[(x<0) & (x>10)]
Out[5]: array([], dtype=int64)

In [6]: x[(x<0) | (x>10)]
Out[6]:
array([-10,  -9,  -8,  -7,  -6,  -5,  -4,  -3,  -2,  -1,  11,  12,  13,
    14,  15,  16,  17,  18,  19])
```

Answer (score 0):

Replacing `and` with `&` in the first one will do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that I was using conditions like `x[(0<x<10) & (20<x<40)]` (I should have guessed from the error message "more than one element") and it is solved by using separating statements i.e. `x[(0<x) & (x<10) & (20<x) & (x<40)]`.