# element-wise comparison, matlab vs python numpy

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, elementwise-operations

I'm a Matlab user and I'm learning Python.
I want to create new arrays with element-wise comparison. 
Using Matlab:
In the example I have solar radiation, temperature and relative humidity:

```
rad=[0,0,0,0,0,12,55,95,50,12,60,12,5,0,0,0];
rhu=[90,91,95,94,93,90,88,89,85,83,81,80,80,85,90,92];
tmp=[3,5,6,9,8,9,10,11,13,15,14,13,11,9,8,8];
```

Now I want to get a new array that contains the temperatures corresponding to solar radiation greater than 50 and relative humidity more than 87. I do:

```
tmp_rad=tmp(rad>50 & rhu>87)
```

In python if I type:

```
rad=np.array([0,0,0,0,0,12,55,95,50,12,60,12,5,0,0,0])
rhu=np.array([90,91,95,94,93,90,88,89,85,83,81,80,80,85,90,92])
tmp=np.array([3,5,6,9,8,9,10,11,13,15,14,13,11,9,8,8])
tmp_rad=tmp[rad>50 and rhu>87]
```

I get the following error "ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()"

Thank you

UPDATE: Sorry I made a mistake: I knew how to treat this firt question but I totally forgot to add the second condition. The problem comes when I want to have two or more comparisons.

Comment: It's just `tmp[rad>=50]`, which square brackets instead of parens. This should be covered very early in any tutorial on numpy.

Answer (score 2):

This is almost the same in numpy as in Matlab:

```
rad=np.array([0,0,0,0,0,12,55,95,50,12,60,12,5,0,0,0])
tmp=np.array([3,5,6,9,8,9,10,11,13,15,14,13,11,9,8,8])
tmp_rad=tmp[rad>=50]
```

The `rad>=50` means exactly what you'd expect. All basic operations—arithmetic, comparisons, etc.—are elementwise, as explained in the [Basic Operations](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/user/quickstart.html#basic-operations) section of the quickstart tutorial. So this returns an array of booleans, where each element is either `True` or `False` depending on whether the corresponding element of `rad` is `>=50` or not.

Python does array indexing with square brackets, as explained in the [Indexing, Slicing and Iterating](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/user/quickstart.html#indexing-slicing-and-iterating) section of the quickstart tutorial. So numpy also uses square brackets for selecting with a boolean array, as explained in the [Indexing with Boolean Arrays](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/user/quickstart.html#indexing-with-boolean-arrays) section of the quickstart tutorial.

Comment: @LuisMendo They all work for me. I've seen the scipy site go down briefly in the past, so maybe that's what happened to you; can you try again?

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found it here: [Numpy array, how to select indices satisfying multiple conditions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3030480/numpy-array-how-to-select-indices-satisfying-multiple-conditions)

I had to replace "and" with "&" and add brackets:

```
tmp_rad=tmp[(rad>50)&(rhu>87)]
```