# Generating scatter plot for a .txt file

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, matplotlib

I'm attempting to plot a scatter plot by extracting information from a txt file where the x-axis is the time taken for my test to finish running and the Y-axis is the time taken for each successful pinging command, which I am able to do using the following block of code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#Read data from file
data = open("EDS4008_2023_04_12.txt",'r')
list = data.readlines()

#Extract time and ping values from the data
time = []
ping_time = []
index = 0

for string in list:
    #print(string)
    index += 1
    if (" time" in string) and (" bytes" in string):
        var1 = string.split(' ')[8]
        #print(var1)
        if "=" in var1:
            t = var1.split("=")[1].split("m")[0]
            ping_time.append(t)
            time.append(index / 60)
        elif "<" in var1:
            t = var1.split("<")[1].split("m")[0]
            ping_time.append(t)
            time.append(index / 60)
        else:
            print("error")
            ping_time.append('0')
            time.append(index / 60)
    else:
        print("skip this line")
        ping_time.append('0')
        time.append(index / 60)


print(ping_time)
print(time)

plt.scatter(time, ping_time)

plt.xlabel('Time (minutes)')
plt.ylabel('Ping Time (ms)')
plt.title('Pinging Duration')

plt.show()
```

Here is the scatter plot:
[image: Plot]

I wanted to know if there was a way for me to remove all the plot points seen at 0 on the Y-axis, and how can I plot a horizontal line that represents the max and min of the readings seen in the txt file that correspond to the Y-axis readings so that the final graph will look something like this:
[image: graph]

Here is an example of what the txt file looks like:
[image: data]

Comment: Your question actually is about two things (not related to how to generate a scatter plot from data in a txt file): (1) how to select data from a list based on a condition (2) how to add horizontal lines to a plot. The answer to (1) can be found e.g. in this post:
(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3030480/how-do-i-select-elements-of-an-array-given-condition) 
In your case it should be something like: `plt.scatter(time[ping_time>0], ping_time[ping_time>0])` The answer to (2) is using `axhline`, see (https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.axhline.html).

Comment: For the first point your method didn't work as ping_time is a list and I get this error when I try it: TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'list' and 'str'

Comment: ① You can use Numpy, please consider that Matplotlib imports Numpy, so importing Numpy yourself is not particularly wasteful ② If you absolutely desire to avoid Numpy, you can collect the "good" data as follows: `x,y=zip(*((x,y)for x,y in zip(t,ping_time)if y>0))`

Answer (score 0):

Since you are constructing your data points after reading the data from the input file, if you don't want the data with a 0 value on the Y-axis, why don't you just don't add them to your data points.

Without doing too much modifications to your code it could look like:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#Read data from file
#data = open("EDS4008_2023_04_12.txt",'r')
input_file = open("input_data.txt")
input_lines = input_file.readlines()

#Extract time and ping values from the data
time = []
ping_time = []
index = 0

for current_line in input_lines:
    #print(string)
    index += 1
    if (" time" in current_line) and (" bytes" in current_line):
        var1 = current_line.split(' ')[8]
        #print(var1)
        if "=" in var1:
            t = var1.split("=")[1].split("m")[0]
            ping_time.append(int(t))
            time.append(index / 60)
        elif "<" in var1:
            t = var1.split("<")[1].split("m")[0]
            ping_time.append(int(t))
            time.append(index / 60)
        else:
            print("error")
            # Don't add this point
            # ping_time.append(0)
            # time.append(index / 60)
    else:
        print("skip this line")
        # Don't add this point
        # ping_time.append(0)
        # time.append(index / 60)


print(ping_time)
print(time)

max_value = max(ping_time)
min_value = min(ping_time)

plt.scatter(time, ping_time)

plt.xlabel('Time (minutes)')
plt.ylabel('Ping Time (ms)')
plt.title('Pinging Duration')
plt.axhline(max_value)
plt.axhline(min_value)

plt.show()
```

- To draw the lines for the max and min of the readings, we use these functions:

  - [min()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#min)
  - [max()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max)
  - [plt.axhline()](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.axhline.html#matplotlib.pyplot.axhline)

I would also stress that you should *not* create variables with generic names because some of these names are already used in the standard library. For example these names already exists:

- [list()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list) is a fondamental class in Python
- [time](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html) is a module of the standard library
- [string](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html) is a module of the standard library

---

But we can do better.

Whenever you have to extract data from text, [regular expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) are one tool that is often useful for this.

```py
import re

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

matcher = re.compile(r'bytes=\d+ time[=<](?P<duration>\d+)ms')

with open("input_data.txt") as input_file:
    ping_time = []
    timestamps = []
    for (line_number, current_line) in enumerate(input_file):
        if line_matched := matcher.search(current_line):
            timestamps.append(line_number / 60)
            ping_time.append(int(line_matched.group('duration')))
        else:
            print('Skip this line')

print(ping_time)
print(timestamps)

max_value = max(ping_time)
min_value = min(ping_time)

plt.scatter(timestamps, ping_time)

plt.xlabel('Time (minutes)')
plt.ylabel('Ping Time (ms)')
plt.title('Pinging Duration')
plt.axhline(max_value)
plt.axhline(min_value)

plt.show()
```

To understand this code you will need to read on:

- Regular expressions using the [re module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html)
- [enumerate()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate)
- Using context managers to make sure a file is closed when you don't need it anymore as described in the [second example](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files) of this section of the official tutorial

---

An advanced way of doing it is using [generators expressions](https://docs.python.org/3.10/tutorial/classes.html#generator-expressions) and [zip()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) in addition to regular expressions to create code that will be a little bit more compact while not keeping all the content of the file in memory.

```py
import re

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

matcher = re.compile(r'bytes=\d+ time[=<](?P<duration>\d+)ms')

with open("input_data.txt") as input_file:
    lines_matched = (matcher.search(current_line) for current_line in input_file)
    data_points = (
        (x / 60, int(current_match.group('duration')))
        for (x, current_match) in enumerate(lines_matched)
        if current_match
    )
    timestamps, ping_time = zip(*data_points)

print(ping_time)
print(timestamps)

max_value = max(ping_time)
min_value = min(ping_time)

plt.scatter(timestamps, ping_time)

plt.xlabel('Time (minutes)')
plt.ylabel('Ping Time (ms)')
plt.title('Pinging Duration')
plt.axhline(max_value)
plt.axhline(min_value)

plt.show()
```

Is is what you were looking for?